# How to multiply a TimeSpan by a percentage

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm trying to multiply a TimeSpan by a coefficient, but I don't know how to do it.

i've tried this:

```
long ErrorCoef = 25;
TimeSpan TotalTimer = new TimeSpan(10,1,2,0);
TimeSpan TotalTimer2 = TimeSpan.FromTicks(TotalTimer.Ticks + TotalTimer.Ticks * (ErrorCoef / 100));
```

but the `(ErrorCoef/100)` is automatically Cast as Long, so it returns 0.

(The TimeSpan.FromTicks() method only accepts Long and not Double)

Comment: try `(ErrorCoef / 100.0)`, so it's a real number

Comment: Either convert the double result to a long, or do the multiplication first, then the division (but watch out for possible numeric overflow): `(TotalTimer.Ticks * ErrorCoef) / 100`.

Comment: why do you calculate your coefficient inline with the ticks? Why not multiply the ticks with 1.25 (or 1.25f) and cast the result to long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timespan has a Multiply method so a

```
var factor = 1.25d;
var totalTimer = new TimeSpan(10,1,2,0);
var totalTimer2 = totalTimer.Multiply(factor);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Specific to .NETCore, v2.0 or higher required.

Comment: This is a good answer when you’re using .NetCore, but actually I’m using .Net Framework (because of WPF UI, which will be only used on Windows environment)